# val-mutable versus var-immutable in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, functional-programming, immutability

Are there any guidelines in Scala on when to use val with a mutable collection versus using var with an immutable collection? Or should you really aim for val with an immutable collection?

The fact that there are both types of collection gives me a lot of choice, and often I don't
know how to make that choice.

Comment: See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999024/scala-var-list-vs-val-mutablelist/11002321#11002321

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Pretty common question, this one. The hard thing is finding the duplicates.

You should strive for *referential transparency*. What that means is that, if I have an expression "e", I could make a `val x = e`, and replace `e` with `x`. This is the property that mutability break. Whenever you need to make a design decision, maximize for referential transparency.

As a practical matter, a method-local `var` is the safest `var` that exists, since it doesn't escape the method. If the method is short, even better. If it isn't, try to reduce it by extracting other methods.

On the other hand, a mutable collection has the *potential* to escape, even if it doesn't. When changing code, you might then want to pass it to other methods, or return it. That's the kind of thing that breaks referential transparency.

On an object (a field), pretty much the same thing happens, but with more dire consequences. Either way the object will have state and, therefore, break referential transparency. But having a mutable collection means even the object itself might lose control of who's changing it.

Comment: Nice, new big picture in my mind: Prefer `immutable val` over `immutable var` over `mutable val` over `mutable var`. Especially `immutable var` over `mutable val`!

Comment: Keep in mind that you could still close (as in leak a side-effecting "function" that can change it) over a local mutable `var`. Another nice feature of using immutable collections is that you can efficiently keep old copies around, even if the `var` mutates.

Comment: tl;dr: prefer `var x: Set[Int]` **over** `val x: mutable.Set[Int]` since if you pass `x` to some other function, in the former case, you are sure, that function cannot mutate `x` for you.

Answer (score 18):

If you work with immutable collections and you need to "modify" them, for example, add elements to them in a loop, then you have to use `var`s because you need to store the resulting collection somewhere. If you only read from immutable collections, then use `val`s.

In general, make sure that you don't confuse references and objects. `val`s are immutable references (constant pointers in C). That is, when you use `val x = new MutableFoo()`, you'll be able **to change the object** that `x` points to, but you won't be able **to change to which object** `x` points. The opposite holds if you use `var x = new ImmutableFoo()`. Picking up my initial advice: if you don't need to change to which object a reference points, use `val`s.

Comment: `var immutable = something(); immutable = immutable.update(x)` defeats the purpose of using an immutable collection.  You've already given up referential transparency and you can usually get the same effect from a mutable collection with better time complexity.  Of the four possibilities (`val` and `var`, mutable and immutable), this one makes the least sense.  I do often use `val mutable`.

Comment: @JimPivarski I disagree, as do others, see Daniel's answer and the comment by Peter. If you need to update a data structure, then using an immutable var instead of a mutable val has the advantage that you can leak references to the structure w/o risking that it is modified by others in a way that breaks your local assumptions. The disadvantage for these "others" is, that they might read stale data.

Comment: I've changed my mind and I agree with you (I'm leaving my original comment for history).  I've since used this, especially in `var list: List[X] = Nil;  list = item :: list;  ...` and I'd forgotten that I once wrote differently.

Comment: @MalteSchwerhoff: "stale data" is actually desirable, depending on how you've designed your program, if consistency is crucial; this is for example one of the main underlying principles in how concurrency works in Clojure.

Comment: @ErikAllik I would not say that stale data is desirable per se, but I agree in that it can be perfectly fine, depending on the guarantees you want/need to give to your clients. Or do you have an example where the sole fact of reading stale data is actually an advantage? I don't mean consequences of accepting stale data, which could be better performance or a simpler API.

Comment: "stale data" is better in a highly concurrent application with a database with temporal aspects: imagine you have an entity A with which you want make some computations, and associate the result with it; if something now changes the globally visible state of A, the association will be inconsistent; whereas if the compuation always sees and works with the "stale" snapshot of A everything will be consistent and the next snapshot of A will have it's own computation results. Basically you're just ignoring the passage of time for short periods for the sake of consistency.

Comment: @MalteSchwerhoff: or just skip what I wrote and read about the underlying concepts and maths behind for example [Clojure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure).

Answer (score 10):

The best way to answer this is with an example.  Suppose we have some process simply collecting numbers for some reason.  We wish to log these numbers, and will send the collection to *another* process to do this.

Of course, we are still collecting numbers after we send the collection to the logger.  And let's say there is some overhead in the logging process that delays the actual logging.  Hopefully you can see where this is going.

If we store this collection in a mutable `val`, (mutable because we are continuously adding to it), this means that the process doing the logging will be looking at the *same object* that's still being updated by our collection process.  That collection may be updated at any time, and so when it's time to log we may not actually be logging the collection we sent.

If we use an immutable `var`, we send an immutable data structure to the logger.  When we add more numbers to our collection, we will be *replacing* our `var` with a *new immutable data structure*.  This doesn't mean collection sent to the logger is replaced!  It's still referencing the collection it was sent.  So our logger will indeed log the collection it received.

Answer (score 2):

I think the examples in this blog post will shed more light, as the question of which combo to use becomes even more important in concurrency scenarios: [importance of immutability for concurrency](http://learningfunctionalprogramming.blogspot.ro/2012/05/importance-of-immutability-for.html). And while we're at it, note the preferred use of synchronised vs @volatile vs something like AtomicReference: [three tools](http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/concurrency.html)

Answer (score -2):

`var immutable` vs. `val mutable`

In addition to many excellent answers to this question. Here is a simple example, that illustrates potential dangers of `val mutable`:

Mutable objects can be modified inside methods, that take them as parameters, while reassignment is not allowed.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object MyObject {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {

        val a = ArrayBuffer(1,2,3,4)
        silly(a)
        println(a) // a has been modified here
    }

    def silly(a: ArrayBuffer[Int]): Unit = {
        a += 10
        println(s"length: ${a.length}")
    }
}
```

Result:

```
length: 5
ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 10)
```

Something like this cannot happen with `var immutable`, because reassignment is not allowed:

```
object MyObject {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        var v = Vector(1,2,3,4)
        silly(v)
        println(v)
    }

    def silly(v: Vector[Int]): Unit = {
        v = v :+ 10 // This line is not valid
        println(s"length of v: ${v.length}")
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
error: reassignment to val
```

Since function parameters are treated as `val` this reassignment is not allowed.

Comment: This is incorrect. The reason you got that error is because you used Vector in your second example which, by default is immutable. If you use an ArrayBuffer you'll see it compiles fine and does the same thing where it just adds in the new element and prints out the mutated buffer. https://pastebin.com/vfq7ytaD

Comment: @EdgeCaseBerg, I am intentionally using a Vector in my second example, because I am trying to show that the behavior of the first example `mutable val` is not possible with the `immutable var`. What here is incorrect?

Comment: You're comparing apples to oranges here. Vector has no `+=` method like array buffer. Your answers implies that `+=` is the same as `x = x + y` which it is not. Your statement that function params are treated as vals is correct and you do get the error you mention but only because you used `=`. 
You can get the same error with an ArrayBuffer so the collections mutability here isn't really relevant. So its not a good answer because its not getting at what the OP is talking about. Though it is a good example of the dangers of passing a mutable collection around if you didn't intend to.

Comment: @EdgeCaseBerg But you can't replicate the behavior I get with `ArrayBuffer`, by using `Vector`. The OP's question is broad, but they were looking for suggestions on when to use which, so I believe my answer is useful because it illustrates dangers of passing around mutable collection (the fact that is `val` does not help); `immutable var` is safer than `mutable val`.