# How can I make this periodic metrics collection code more functional (less mutable state)?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, akka

Here is the outline of my code

There are multiple worker actors and I am collecting some latency stats from them into `httpActorLatencies` map where latency from each worker actor is tracked separately and then logged on receiving `LogQueueLatency` message. At this point, all the queues in `httpActorLatencies` are also cleared.

Is there a way to get rid of mutable Map in a reasonable way?

```
class StatsActor(workerCount: Int) extends Actor {
  val httpActorLatencies = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[Long]]()

  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    Range(0, workerCount).foreach(i => httpActorLatencies.put(i, scala.collection.mutable.MutableList()))
  }

  override def receive = {
    case shardLatency: QueuingLatency =>
      httpActorLatencies(shardLatency.shardNumber) += shardLatency.latency

    case LogQueueLatency =>
      outputCollectedStats()
  }

  private def outputCollectedStats(): Unit = {
    output(StatsActor.computePerShardMeanLatencies(httpActorLatencies))
    httpActorLatencies.foreach(x => x._2.clear())
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to start, prefer var of mutable collection over a val of a mutable one, as var will be kept on the scope and not leak by message to another actor... 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386559/val-mutable-versus-var-immutable-in-scala ;)

using become, as proposed by Tim answer you can avoid the var all together

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is to use `context.become` and a receive function that carries the `Map` with it, like this:

```
class StatsActor extends Actor {
  def newMap() = Map[Int, List[Long]]().withDefault(Nil)

  def receive: Receive = countingReceive(newMap())

  def countingReceive(httpActorLatencies: Map[Int, List[Long]]): Receive = {
    case shardLatency: QueuingLatency =>
      val newList = httpActorLatencies(shardLatency.shardNumber) :+ shardLatency.latency
      val newMap = httpActorLatencies.updated(shardLatency.shardNumber, newList)

      context.become(countingReceive(newMap))

    case LogQueueLatency =>
      outputCollectedStats(httpActorLatencies)

      context.become(receive)
  }


  private def outputCollectedStats(httpActorLatencies: Map[Int, List[Long]]): Unit = {
    ...
  }
}
```

This is untested and probably broken, but it should give an idea of how it might be done.

Also note that I have used `withDefault` on the `Map` to make the logic simpler and remove the need for a `workerCount`.